# Distributing a Java application with an Embedded Apache Derby database

Tags: java, derby

So i currently have a java application that uses an Apache derby embedded database to store information regarding the user.

I built the application in Netbeans, and it now resides within the dist folder, the folder contains the `executable jar`, the Apache database, and the lib folder. so I can launch the application by selecting the executable jar but i don't want to distribute this folder to users, I would rather have a single `exe` that the user can select instead of giving them the folder that has the `executable jar`and other folders within it.
I have been looking into tools like launch4j but they don't do what i need.

Is it possible to create a exe that contains a derby database?

EDIT

also I need to write to the database to store users details.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you'd need to use some sort of installer so user installs your folder structure somewhere, and u can give them shortcut that java .. launches your app. Maybe something like https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Installer-Framework

Comment: You can deploy your application as one jar file, with the **readonly** database embedded in the jar.  See https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevdeploy15325.html

Comment: I have thought about having the embedded database in a jar but i need to write to the database to store users info.

Comment: Ok, so you don't want to embed the database in your Java application.  ;-)  You want the database to be installed on the user's file system.  You still can use an embedded read-only copy of the database to create/populate the database on the user's file system.  If the question is about including the derby jar files, you can make an "uber jar" by unpacking and repacking the jars into the final application jar.  Or you could use [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) to package multiple jars into one.  Or you could use Java Web Start to download/install the required jars.

Comment: Here i was thinking i was smart for using an embedded database XD, right so i have to determine a suitable location on the users machine and create the database there, honestly i dont even know where to start with that. might just be easier to distribute the folder instead :(

Comment: I always used `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".appname");` for my app's storage.